# addEventListener on dynamically created elements doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```js
const monthAndYear = document.querySelector(".monthAndYear");
const habitContent = document.querySelector(".js-habit-content");
const trackerBody = document.querySelector(".js-tracker-body");

let today = new Date();
let currentMonth = today.getMonth();
let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
const months = [
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec",
];


function showTracker(month, year) {
  const selectedDate = new Date(year, month);
  const lastDate = new Date(
    selectedDate.getFullYear(),
    selectedDate.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  );

  let date = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      if (date <= lastDate.getDate()) {
        const cell = document.createElement("td");
        const cellPtag = document.createElement("p");
        const cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
        const cellIcon = document.createElement("i");
        cell.setAttribute("class", "habit-count");
        cellIcon.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-star star-icon");
        cellPtag.appendChild(cellText);
        cell.appendChild(cellPtag);
        cell.appendChild(cellIcon);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        date++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    trackerBody.appendChild(row);
  }
}

showTracker(currentMonth, currentYear);

document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches(".fa-star")) {
    e.target.classList.toggle("selected");
  }
});
```

```css
.tracker-items {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
}

.habit-count {
  padding: 0 10px 15px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.habit-count:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.habit-count p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.star-icon {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #c2b7b0;
}

.selected {
  color: #f4df21;
}
```

```html
<div class="tracker-main">
  <table class="traker-items">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody class="js-tracker-body"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha256-HkXXtFRaflZ7gjmpjGQBENGnq8NIno4SDNq/3DbkMgo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I'm trying to build a habit tracker and want to change color of fontawesome icon when clicked.
But somehow it doesn't work well.

```
function showTracker(month, year) {
  const selectedDate = new Date(year, month);
  const lastDate = new Date(
    selectedDate.getFullYear(),
    selectedDate.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  );

  monthAndYear.innerHTML = `${months[month]} ${year}`;
  trackerBody.innerHTML = "";

  let date = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      if (date <= lastDate.getDate()) {
        const cell = document.createElement("td");
        const cellPtag = document.createElement("p");
        const cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
        const cellIcon = document.createElement("i");
        cell.setAttribute("class", "habit-count");
        cellIcon.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-star star-icon");
        cellPtag.appendChild(cellText);
        cell.appendChild(cellPtag);
        cell.appendChild(cellIcon);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        date++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    trackerBody.appendChild(row);
  }
}

showTracker(currentMonth, currentYear);

document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches(".fa-star")) {
    e.target.classList.toggle("selected");
  }
});
```

I understand you cannot directly use querySelectorAll and then addEventListener on dynamically created element. It works randomly if I click several times but still toggle doesn't work at all.
Any help would be really really appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve] using the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Hi. I added the live demo feature. Thanks for letting me know this feature!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the generated DOM, and add a `console.log(e.target)` before your `if` statement.

[image]

While you are creating an `<i>` element, font-awesome is replacing it with an `<svg>` element containing a `<path>`.

The `<svg>` element is a member of the class, but the `<path>` element is not.

As a result, the toggle only works if you click on the SVG image *outside of the area covered by the star*.

You could change the logic so it tests if the element clicked on is the SVG itself or the `<path>` that draws the star inside it.

```
if (e.target && e.target.matches(".fa-star") || e.target && e.target.parentNode.matches(".fa-star")) {
```

… or search the DOM for any ancestor which matches it (which would work with more complex SVGs).

```
if (e.target.closest(".fa-star"))
```

Closest will match the element itself (it doesn't target *only* ancestors). You can dispense with the test to see if `e.target` exists because it **always** will in a click event.

Comment: @AnuragHazra — Ah, yes, that would be a better approach. I hadn't realised it had achieved decent browser support.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is to attach the event listener do the element when you create it:

```
function showTracker(month, year) {
  const selectedDate = new Date(year, month);
  const lastDate = new Date(
    selectedDate.getFullYear(),
    selectedDate.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  );

  monthAndYear.innerHTML = `${months[month]} ${year}`;
  trackerBody.innerHTML = "";

  let date = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      if (date <= lastDate.getDate()) {
        const cell = document.createElement("td");
        const cellPtag = document.createElement("p");
        const cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
        const cellIcon = document.createElement("i");
        cell.setAttribute("class", "habit-count");
        cellIcon.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-star star-icon");
        cellIcon.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.target.classList.toggle("selected");
        });
        cellPtag.appendChild(cellText);
        cell.appendChild(cellPtag);
        cell.appendChild(cellIcon);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        date++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    trackerBody.appendChild(row);
  }
}

showTracker(currentMonth, currentYear);
```

Comment: I tried this one (even though I wanted to keep '1 function do 1 role' kinda rule) but didn't work. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: With this approach you will face performance issues and memory leaks.. because you are looping through every item and adding the event listener but not removing the old ones. the optimal way is `Event Delegation`